# Error trying to install jupyter notebook for anaconda 3.8.3

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, anaconda3

Using Anaconda 3.8.3 im trying to install the jupyter notebook but it is giving me an error

```
C:\Users\user>conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64'
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try download jupyterlab from [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/jupyterlab/#files).

Then use `canoda install path/jupyterlab-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl`.